# K8S "cannot exec into or attach to a container using host network"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

in k8s  yaml

spec:
hostPID: true
hostNetwork: true
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet

when the pod running
exec the shell  " kubectl exec -it podId -- /bin/sh"
show the error .

cannot exec into or attach to a container using host network

Comment: Please take a moment to properly format your question (there is help available from the editor). In particular, make sure your manifest is formatted as a code sample.

Comment: The error message pretty much means what it says.  You shouldn't need either `hostPID:` or `hostNetwork:` in ordinary use.  (Nor should you normally need `kubectl exec`, since any changes you make there will only affect one replica of a Deployment and will be lost as soon as that Pod is deleted, possibly outside your direct control.)